# Расширить функциональность метода без наследования

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, логирование

Есть абстрактный класс с абстрактным методом по parse().
И есть дочерние классы, реализующие этот метод.
В них метод parse() свою функцию выполняет. И, там есть такой код:

```
class XmlParser extends Parser {
    public function parse() {
        ...
        if (!$item->validate()) {
            continue;
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

И так в каждом реализующем классе.
Проблема в том, что мне надо с непрошедшими валидацию строками производить в дальнейшем определенные действия, например логировать их.

Но решение - захардкодить логирование в методе parse() каждого реализующего класса - не из лучших. То есть такое решение не комильфо:

```
 class XmlParser extends Parser {
        public function parse() {
            ...
            if (!$item->validate()) {
                log($item); //хардкод - это плохо
                continue;
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Потому что вдруг надо будет еще делать уведомление по email об ошибках, придется снова лезть в каждый из этих классов и хардкодить.

Возможно применить какой-нибудь паттерн?

Answer (score 0):

В подобной ситуации я выделил бы отдельный класс обработчик, и передавал бы его в вызывающий класс, а в parce вызывал бы его метод обработки ошибок валидации.

```
$this->logger->proccess_validate_error( $item );
```

а в зависимости от требований к обработчику, создал свой класс обработки.